# Mac - Copy/paste charts from Excel to Powerpoint via VBA (Excel/PPT V.16.35)

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Hi I am trying to copy Charts from an Excel Sheet and paste them in an Powerpoint Slide.
I've tried two ways of implementing it in VBA.

1.Option:
failed - doesn't support property or method > PasteSpecial.

```
For i = 1 To 10
    ppFile.Slides(i + 1).Select

    Worksheets("Darstellung").ChartObjects(i).CopyPicture

    Set objShape = ppFile.Slides(i + 1).Shapes.PasteSpecial(Datatype:=ppPasteDefault)'<<< problem in this line

With objShape
    .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    .ScaleWidth 1.5, msoTrue
    .ScaleHeight 1.9, msoFalse


    .Top = 100
    .Height = 350
    .Width = 700
    .Left = 150
End With

Set objShape = Nothing

Next
```

2.Option: 
semi failed - works but needs 1 and half minute to paste one chart and throws exception: "excel is waiting for another application to complete an ole action" after every chart. Clicking ok lets the VBA run and paste the next chart.

```
For i = 1 To 10
    ppFile.Slides(i + 1).Select

    Worksheets("Darstellung").ChartObjects(i).CopyPicture

    Set objShape = ppFile.Slides(i + 1).Shapes.Paste '<<< problem in this line

With objShape
    .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    .ScaleWidth 1.5, msoTrue
    .ScaleHeight 1.9, msoFalse


    .Top = 100
    .Height = 350
    .Width = 700
    .Left = 150
End With

Set objShape = Nothing

Next
```

Is there any way to implement it on Mac, so it runs properly and efficient?

Comment: Have you tried other datatypes with your first example? Here is Microsoft's page showing alternatives: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shapes.pastespecial VBA in PowerPoint for Mac is pretty bad. The object model is full of holes, as illustrated in your first block of code. I've stopped using the Mac version and only program in PowerPoint for Windows.

Comment: @JohnKorchok yes, I've tried every DataType, but no matter what DataType I've tried, it still says "doesn't support property or method". So I guess that PasteSpecial doesn't exist on Mac. Well, I am usually programming on Windows too, but I have to spread this document among Mac Users as well. So it has to work on Mac as well. :(

Comment: I have longstanding working code that pastes Excel charts into PowerPoint, works great in Windows. But on a Mac, PowerPoint and Excel exist in separate sandboxes, and communication between them is at best unreliable. I gave up on this feature for Mac long ago. Perhaps I could try again, or I could pull out my beard whisker-by-whisker.